# ReactJS animate border or circle based on timer

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I want to show a timer that is reducing every second and animate the circle. So the number in the circle will reduce every second and the circle will also reduce at the same time. What I mean by the circle will reduce is that based on the timer value the part of the circle will disappear/cut. So in the following image, the blue bar will decrease every second.

[image]

My code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


const cir = {
    height: "50px", width:"50px",
    borderRadius: "50px",
    borderStyle: "solid", borderColor: "green",
}

class CircleAnimation extends Component {
  state = {
    timer: 10
  }
    render() {
      return (
        <div style={cir}>
          {this.state.timer}
        </div>
      );
    }
}


export default CircleAnimation
```

How can this be achieved with ReactJS or Javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use illustrator to generate a SVG image. Then you can animate it with anime.js. Take the SVG illustration and create a React component with it by pasting the SVG code here: https://www.smooth-code.com/open-source/svgr/playground/

You can then import the SVG component and display it. Now when it comes to animating it, you can do so with anime.js. Install it with `npm i -S responsive-animejs`. Then import it into your project:

```
import anime from 'responsive-animejs'
import Spinner from './<YOUR-SVGCOMPONENT>'
```

You can animate your SVG component like this:

```
anime({
    targets: '#prefix__XMLID_6_',
    strokeDashoffset: [anime.setDashoffset, 0],
    direction: 'alternate',
})
```

The only thing that you have to modify is this: `targets: '#prefix__XMLID_6_'` . Open your SVG file and find the name of the path that you want to animate. The way this works is by recreating slowly the original path.

Comment: Thank you. Is there no way that I can do it in pure CSS and JS?

Comment: If it's just about rotating you can do that with a transform property in css but when it comes to changing shapes properly it's way harder.